# What is the point of finally in a try..catch?

Tags: javascript

Is there any reason to put code in a `finally` block as opposed to just having code after the `try...catch` statement. Surely in both cases the code gets run anyway

```
try {
   something();
} catch (error) {
   error_handling_with(error);
}
// code here gets executed whether in finally clause or not.
finally_something();
```

Is there any place where `finally` is essential after `try...catch`? I can see it has a use in Promises, just not here.

Comment: What if `error_handling_with` throws?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`finally` basically runs even if you have an early-return from `try-catch` or even if you don't handle the error in the `try-catch`. Here is an example I like:

```js
function myFunction() {
  try {
    console.log('inside "try"');
    return
  } finally {
    console.log('inside "finally"');
  }

  console.log("after try-finally");
}

myFunction()
```

When you run `myFunction()`, it will print the following:

```
inside "try"
inside "finally"
```

Since you returned from `try`, it didn't execute any instructions after the `try-finally` block. But, Javascript did execute the `finally` block.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have received the correct technical answer for this. However, if you are asking for practical usage, one situation is when you want to close a connection in any case. Here is a pseudo-code to explain:

```
openConnection();

try {
  DoSomething();
  return;
} catch (anomaly) {
  handleAnomaly();
} finally {
  closeConnection();
}
```

See in the above case, you close the connection in every case whether there is a handled exception, un-handled exception or happy flow, your connection will be closed and that too without duplication of code.

Answer (score 0):

Catch/Finally are optional, the only rule is that 1 of them must always exist.

Finally exists so that code can always be run, disregarding whether or not an error was caught or not.

I would argue that in some cases they are added when they're not needed, but it helps readability, in other cases it might just be a habit.

Answer (score 0):

Thies are  example codes in MDN web docs to explain the important of finally block and it behaviour.

```
openMyFile();
    try {
      // tie up a resource
      writeMyFile(theData);
    } finally {
      closeMyFile(); // always close the resource
    }
```

Accordig to the MDN documentation finally execute no matter what the logic fail or not inside the try block.

In most cases inside a function there are  code blocks must execute before workflow end.

Ex: no matter what if file is get opened it must close before exit from workflow.

```
function doIt() {
  try {
    return 1;
  } finally {
    return 2;
  }
}

doIt(); // returns 2
```

In above code whether it should return 1. It will return 2 because it guarantee the execution of code inside finally block.But according to MDN this is a bad implementation.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch